# ASA 5505 Blocking traffic

Tags: cisco-asa

This 5505 is blocking traffic both in and out. I have asked for help from good IT guys and they say it looks like it is configured correctly. It was working a week ago. I show the config here. If anyone can help I would sure appreciate it.

```
CrazyQASA# show running-config
: Saved
:
ASA Version 8.2(5)
!
terminal width 300
hostname CrazyQASA
domain-name CrazyQ.com

names
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 switchport access vlan 2
!

interface Vlan1
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.60.81.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan2
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address 198.121.179.194 255.255.255.248
!
ftp mode passive
clock timezone CST -6
clock summer-time CDT recurring
dns domain-lookup inside
dns domain-lookup outside
dns server-group DefaultDNS
 name-server 209.32.32.32
 name-server 206.8.8.8
 domain-name crazq.com
object-group service rdp3390 tcp
 port-object eq 3390
access-list inboundtraffic extended permit tcp any interface outside eq pptp
CrazyQASA# ping 8.8.8.8
Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 8.8.8.8, timeout is 2 seconds:
!!!!!
Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 40/40/40 ms
CrazyQASA# ping 10.60.81.1
Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 10.60.81.1, timeout is 2 seconds:
!!!!!
Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 1/1/1 ms
CrazyQASA# show route

Codes: C - connected, S - static, I - IGRP, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
   D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
   N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
   E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2, E - EGP
   i - IS-IS, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2, ia - IS-IS inter area
   * - candidate default, U - per-user static route, o - ODR
   P - periodic downloaded static route

Gateway of last resort is 198.121.179.194 to network 0.0.0.0

C    198.121.179.192 255.255.255.248 is directly connected, outside
C    10.60.81.0 255.255.255.0 is directly connected, inside
S*   0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 [1/0] via 198.121.179.194, outside
CrazyQASA#
```

Comment: I dont see your NATing rule or default route command. I would rerun the setup wizard to make it create them all for you, as it seem a simple config you have

Answer (score 0):

You can use the packet-tracer command to trouble shoot this.  You specify the characteristics of the traffic you're trying to troubleshoot, and it will evaluate it against the ASA's config telling you exactly what would happen if that traffic actually did hit your ASA.

[Cisco forum post that describes packet-tracer](https://supportforums.cisco.com/document/29601/troubleshooting-access-problems-using-packet-tracer)

Comment: Here is result.. not sure how to fix this:

Comment: Looks like your traffic is being blocked by the implicit deny any at the bottom of every ACL.  I don't see how your ACLs are bound to your interfaces in your config dump so I can't say which might be causing your issue.    Here's a link describing how to setup ACLs on an ASA (version 8.2). http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa82/configuration/guide/config/access_nw.html#wpxref71793

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think with what you gave me I can probably get there. It's fantastic you are out there to help!

Comment: I am not getting through this. If I post more info could you possibly help me?

Comment: I need to allow inbound traffic so people can vpn in. That is the main issue. Not sure how it stopped working. I did a password recovery procedure and it was working after that was completed but not people can not hit the server

Comment: What does your running config look like now?

Comment: this comment section only lets me post about 500 characters. Can I get it to you some how?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Sx3ZztWTnB5dESSA9_moJM4qWrEzoqvX3NNU-ul60ks/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You should be able to get to this google doc

Comment: So first off I wouldn't put your full unedited config online like this.  Items like your enable password are sensitive.  You should pull that Google doc and change the passwords on your ASA before continuing.  Next, have you verified yourself the VPN is being blocked at your ASA?  This is something you could use the packet-tracer command to do.  I'm guessing your NAT configuration is part of your issue, look through this article: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa82/configuration/guide/config/nat_control.html

Comment: I was afraid i shouldn't post the whole config. I will get the pw changed shortly. Dropped the google folder already.

Comment: I had 50 people over to see my new grandson yesterday. One of them, my nephew, was a networking guy. He said it was an ARP issue. Not sure on all the details but what he did was, force the MAC address to something different than it was (on the nic), then rebooted the machine, then changed it back to what was on the NIC. This fixed everything. VPN started working, DNS started working and everybody was happy.

Comment: Thanks again for looking at this.  Weird, i thought for sure it was the router.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a network ARP issue not a CISCO issue. To fix it we forced the MAC address to something different than it was (on the nic), then rebooted the machine, then changed it back to what was on the NIC. This fixed everything. VPN started working, DNS started working and everybody was happy. Sorry I don't have the full explanation of the why's of all this but it worked.